# How to get current time in jinja

Tags: jinja2

What is the method to get current date time value in `jinja` tags ?

On my project I need to show current time in UTC at top right corner of site.

Comment: If what you mentioned is all the requirement, Consider using moment.js at the client level as in http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-dates-and-times

Comment: if moment.js is a option I don't think it's worth asking.because every one knows how to get current time in python..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I like @Assem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252044/117471). I'm going to demo it in a Jinja2 template.

```python
#!/bin/env python3
import datetime
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""
# Generation started on {{ now() }}
... this is the rest of my template...
# Completed generation.
""")

template.globals['now'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow

print(template.render())
```

Output:

```
# Generation started on 2017-11-14 15:48:06.507123
... this is the rest of my template...
# Completed generation.
```

Note:

I rejected an edit from someone who stated "datetime.datetime.utcnow() is a method, not a property". While they are "correct", they misunderstood the intention of NOT including the `()`. Including `()` causes the method to be called at the time the object `template.globals['now']` is defined. That would cause every use of `now` in your template to render the same value rather than getting a current result from `datetime.datetime.utcnow`.

Comment: In case of Django, the recommended way is to use [`django.utils.timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/).

Answer (score 9):

You should use `datetime` library of Python, get the time and pass it as a variable to the template:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
'2015-05-15 05:22:17.953439'
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who wants to add the `now` tag back into Jinja2 permanently, there is a great example for how to add it as a Jinja extension here:
https://www.webforefront.com/django/useandcreatejinjaextensions.html

This requires defining a new Jinja extension within a python script inside your Django web app, and then importing it as an extension in `settings.py`.

In `your_web_app/some_file.py` (I put it in the same directory as `settings.py`):

```
from jinja2 import lexer, nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime


class DjangoNow(Extension):
    tags = set(['now'])

    def _now(self, date_format):
        tzinfo = timezone.get_current_timezone() if settings.USE_TZ else None
        formatted = date(datetime.now(tz=tzinfo),date_format)
        return formatted

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        token = parser.stream.expect(lexer.TOKEN_STRING)
        date_format = nodes.Const(token.value)
        call = self.call_method('_now', [date_format], lineno=lineno)
        token = parser.stream.current
        if token.test('name:as'):
            next(parser.stream)
            as_var = parser.stream.expect(lexer.TOKEN_NAME)
            as_var = nodes.Name(as_var.value, 'store', lineno=as_var.lineno)
            return nodes.Assign(as_var, call, lineno=lineno)
        else:
            return nodes.Output([call], lineno=lineno)
```

Then, in `settings.py`, add the DjangoNow class to the `extensions` list under `OPTIONS` within `TEMPLATES`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    { 
        'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': { 
            ...,
            'extensions': [
                'your-app-name.some-file.DjangoNow',
                ],
        }       
   }
]
```

Then you can use the now tag just as you would use it with Django, for example:

```
{% now 'U' %}
```

Comment: In case of Django, you can pass `django.utils.timezone.now()` to the template and there: `{{ localtime(now) }}`. That is if you're using `django-jinja`. If not, I suppose you can still make use of `django.templatetags.tz.localtime`.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, but finally found [jinja2-time](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2-time/):

```py
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2_time.TimeExtension'])

# Timezone 'local', default format -> "2015-12-10"
template = env.from_string("{% now 'local' %}")

# Timezone 'utc', explicit format -> "Thu, 10 Dec 2015 15:49:01"
template = env.from_string("{% now 'utc', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S' %}")

# Timezone 'Europe/Berlin', explicit format -> "CET +0100"
template = env.from_string("{% now 'Europe/Berlin', '%Z %z' %}")

# Timezone 'utc', explicit format -> "2015"
template = env.from_string("{% now 'utc', '%Y' %}")

template.render()
```

More about jinja2-time extension installation:

> jinja2-time is available for download from PyPI via pip:
>
> `$ pip install jinja2-time`
>
> It will automatically install jinja2 along with arrow.

Comment: FYI this package hasn't been updated in 6 years.

Comment: And you commented on a 3-year-old post? Okay

Comment: yep, I'm crazy like that!

Answer (score 1):

To add the current date stamp to an HTML document generated from a HTML template using Jinja2:

```html
#In the HTML template do:
{{ date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') }} <!-- Output format "Month DD, YYYY" -->
```

(Minimum) Python code:

```py
## Tested in Python 3.6.8
import os
import datetime
import jinja2 

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

#When building the values to pass to jinja
self.datapool=dict()
self.datapool['date']= datetime.datetime.now()

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('./templates/base-html-template.html')
report=template.render(self.datapool)
```