# How I can use Airflow template reference in the DAG python code

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am new in the Airflow world and trying to understand one thing. For example I have a DAG that contains 2 tasks. The first task is submitting spark job, and the second one is Sensor that waits for a file in s3.

```
RUN_DATE_ARG = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT_PY)
DATE = datetime.strptime(RUN_DATE_ARG, DATE_FORMAT_PY) - timedelta(hours=1)
with DAG() as dag:


submit_spark_job = EmrContainerOperator(
    task_id="start_job",
    virtual_cluster_id=VIRTUAL_CLUSTER_ID,
    execution_role_arn=JOB_ROLE_ARN,
    release_label="emr-6.3.0-latest",
    job_driver=JOB_DRIVER_ARG,
    configuration_overrides=CONFIGURATION_OVERRIDES_ARG,
    name=f"spark-{RUN_DATE_ARG}",
    retries=3
)

validate_s3_success_file = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='check_for_success_file',
    bucket_name="bucket-name",
    bucket_key=f"blabla/date={DATE.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}/hour={DATE.strftime('%H')}/_SUCCESS",
    poke_interval=10,
    timeout=60,
    verify=False,
)
```

I have a RUN_DATE_ARG that by default should be taken from `datetime.utcnow()` and this is one of sparks java arguments that I should provide to my job.
I want to add an ability to submit job with custom date argument (via airflow UI).
When I am trying to retrieve it as `'{{ dag_run.conf["date"] | None}}'` it replaces with value inside task configuration (`bucket_key=f"blabla/date={DATE.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}/hour={DATE.strftime('%H')}/_SUCCESS",`), but not for DAG's python code if I do following:

```
date='{{ dag_run.conf["date"] | None}}'
if date is None:
  RUN_DATE_ARG = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT_PY)
else: 
  RUN_DATE_ARG = date
```

Do I have any way to use this value as a code variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use templating outside of operators scope.

You should use Jinja if statements in the operator templated parameter. The following is just a general idea:

```
submit_spark_job = EmrContainerOperator(
    task_id="start_job",
    ...
    name="spark-{{ dag_run.conf["date"] if dag_run.conf["date"] is not None else jinja_utc_now }}",

)
```

You will need to replace `jinja_utc_now` with code that retrieve the timestamp probably something like what is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104914/how-to-get-current-time-in-jinja/51641667) answer.

You can also use:

```
{% if something %}
   code
{% else %}
   another code
{% endif %}
```

From Airflow point of view it takes the parameter and pass it though Jinja engine for templating so the key issue here is just to use the proper Jinja syntax.